# How to subset data based on combination of criteria in R

Tags: r, subset

I have a several million rows of data and I need to create a subset. No success despite of trying hard and searching all over the web. The question is:

**How to create a subset including only the smallest values of `value` for all `ID` & `item` combinations?**

The data structure looks like this:

```
> df = data.frame(ID = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2),
            item = c('A','A','B','B','A','A','B','B'),
            value = c(10,5,3,2,7,8,9,10))

> df
   ID item value
1  1    A    10
2  1    A     5
3  1    B     3
4  1    B     2
5  2    A     7
6  2    A     8
7  2    B     9
8  2    B    10
```

The the result should look like this:

```
  ID item value
  1    A     5
  1    B     2
  2    A     7
  2    B     9
```

Any hints greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `aggregate` from `baseR` with grouping variables 'ID' and 'item' to get the `min` of 'value'

```
aggregate(value~., df, min)
#  ID item value
#1  1    A     5
#2  2    A     7
#3  1    B     2
#4  2    B     9
```

---

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(ID, item) %>%
   summarise(value = min(value))
```

---

Or with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(value = min(value)) , .(ID, item)]
```

Or another option would be to `order` and get the `first` row after grouping

```
setDT(df)[order(value), head(.SD, 1), .(ID, item)]
```